# Spring REST API modifying "oauth/token" org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint TokenEndpoint to return additional Info

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth

Hello I am looking for some help with spring security, i have a Spring REST API servicing IOS and Android stack, we have a oauth/token endpoint which is used to login to the application, upon confirmation it sends back token. its a out the box spring security class org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint. I am trying to send in the response additional information from the api related to the user to consolidate api calls from mobile device upon login.  I am not sure how to do this, or what the best approach would be...  Should I create a new TokenEndpoint class?  This is how I have some of the XML configured for the spring-security.

```
 <!-- OAUTH CONFIGS -->
<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="hcnavigator" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

TokenEnhancer (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenEnhancer.html) is what you need. You can inject it to your token service (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.html). The TokenEnhancer will be called after the token is generated and you can add additional information to your token response inside its `enhance(...)` method.

Comment: happy to hear that :)